# Getting value based on datetime object intervals in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following election data:

```
    Date        Winner
0   1910-04-13  ALP
1   1913-05-31  L+NP
2   1914-09-05  ALP
3   1917-05-05  L+NP
4   1919-12-13  L+NP
```

How can I calculate the current elected party for a given date not explicitly stated in the dataset?

For example when I try the following code I get an empty series back

```
df['Winner'][df['Date'].dt.year == 1916]
```

How can I get the previous election result from that date of ALP?

Comment: How do you handle years like `1917` when `ALP` and `L+NP` were both winners?

Comment: I would state month and day as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach is to make new column and compare:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['End'] = df['Date'].shift(-1) - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
df['End'].fillna(pd.datetime.now(), inplace=True)
```

New `df`:

```
        Date Winner                        End
0 1910-04-13    ALP 1913-05-30 00:00:00.000000
1 1913-05-31   L+NP 1914-09-04 00:00:00.000000
2 1914-09-05    ALP 1917-05-04 00:00:00.000000
3 1917-05-05   L+NP 1919-12-12 00:00:00.000000
4 1919-12-13   L+NP 2019-06-09 15:43:14.319334
```

Then use logical comparison:

```
q = pd.datetime(1916, 10, 1)
df['Winner'][(df['Date'] < q) & (q < df['End'])]
```

Output:

```
2    ALP
Name: Winner, dtype: object
```